# Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, ngx-bootstrap

I'm having an issue in my application with ngx-bootstrap whereby it now can't detect the module unless you specify the path

For example:

```
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

produces "**Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap'**".

Removing the reference and checking quickfixes just replaces the reference with:

```
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/public_api';
```

Obviously this isn't ideal as they should be available through ngx-bootstrap without specifying the folder, and i would have to go through dozens of components and change these references which shouldn't be necessary. Has anyone had this problem before?

I've already tried:

- `npm install`
- `npm update` in case there were updates in recent commits
- Deleting node_modules folder and doing `npm install` again
- Re-installing ngx-bootstrap on its own - `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`
- `npm cache clean`
- I've even started afresh and cloned my app into another location, run `npm install`, and the same thing happens

This was working fine yesterday. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**More info:**

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.2
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 9.0.1
```

package.json:

```
    "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.7",
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.1",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngx-progressbar/core": "^5.3.2",
    "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^9.0.3",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "angular-9-datatable": "^0.1.1",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.2",
    "angular-gauge": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-gridster2": "^9.0.1",
    "angular-resize-event": "^1.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "ckeditor4-angular": "^1.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "echarts": "^4.7.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "^6.1.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng4-charts": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "ngx-color": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.2.2",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^8.0.4",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.1.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.4",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "valid-url": "^1.0.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.1",
    "@types/echarts": "^4.4.4",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.8",
    "@types/pluralize": "0.0.29",
    "@types/valid-url": "^1.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
    "tslint": "~6.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.7.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.1"
  },
```

If anyone has any ideas let me know

Thanks!

Answer (score 67):

Based on **[ngx-bootstrap documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)**, `angular` 9 doesn't support this kind of import . If you want to use `BsModalService` , `ButtonsModule` and so on you have to import them as below :

```
// RECOMMENDED
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ButtonsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/buttons';
```

instead of :

```
// NOT RECOMMENDED
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef , ButtonsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 13):

As per https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5753

Updated documentation: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

```
 // RECOMMENDED
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
// NOT RECOMMENDED (Angular 9 doesn't support this kind of import)
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

This is the ideal solution as it is the one that is documented by the maintainer of the repo.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem today, trying to update from Angular **9.0.2** to Angular **9.1.0**.

I guess it's because you have in your **package.json**: **"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2"**, so npm is taking the latest version available on ngx-bootrap tag: **5.6.0**. (At least that's the version I have today)

I've solved just replacing the imports on my code, from **'ngx-bootstrap'** to **'ngx-bootstrap/someBootstrapComponent'**.

For example, my previous import was:

```
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

And my new import looks like:

```
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
```

I know this is not an ideal solution, but meanwhile at least you can have your app compiling properly.

I hope it helps.

Best regards,
Jesús.

Comment: Thanks Jesús. It's strange as I work on a dev team with 5 other guys using the same project, and it's not happening for any of them. We upgraded angular about a month ago so don't think it has anything to do with any sort of update. Very weird! If all else fails I will have to replace all the imports but I might hold off and see if anyone else has any ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

So it seems like it might be a problem with later versions of ngx-bootstrap. In my package.json, I replaced `"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2"` with `"ngx-bootstrap": "5.3.2"`, ran `npm install` and it built without any problems.

Answer (score 6):

> import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

This must be working .. simple solution

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the same package.json that's ran before, now doesn't works. The advice above work like a charm.
Solution: remove the ^.
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2" to "ngx-bootstrap": "5.3.2"

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Angular 9 with the latest version of ngx-bootstrap.
I believe the latest implementation is to import the BsDatepickerModule in the app.module.ts file like this

**Import statement in app.module.ts code:**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
```

**in app.module.ts imports:**

```
  imports: [
BrowserAnimationsModule,
BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()
```

]

**Component Code:**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BsDatepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Component({ selector: 'app-', templateUrl: './register.component.html', styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {


bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;



constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {

this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, { containerClass: 'theme-blue' });

}
}
```

**package.json**

"@angular/core": "~9.1.7",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
"@angular/cli": "~9.1.6"
[image]

**From the official site:**

**Usage**

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

// RECOMMENDED

import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

// NOT RECOMMENDED (Angular 9 doesn't support this kind of import)

import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({

imports: [

```
BrowserAnimationsModule,

BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),

...
```

]
})

export class AppModule(){}

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

[techjunkieblog.com](https://www.techjunkieblog.com)